# getting boolean from shared preference always returns false

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I store my boolean like this in my preference activity:

```
OnPreferenceChangeListener locaListener = new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {    
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                if(newValue.toString().trim().equals("true")){
                    editor.putBoolean("locationEnabled", true);
                }else if (newValue.toString().trim().equals("false")){
                    editor.putBoolean("locationEnabled", false);
                }
                editor.commit();
                return true;
            }
        };
```

and try to retrieve it like this in my main activity:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
boolean prefLocationEnabled = prefs.getBoolean("locationEnabled", false);
```

Same approach with string works perfect but with boolean it seems to return always the default value which is false. Anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `editor.putBoolean("locationEnabled", true);` is being called?  Does `newValue.toString().trim().equals("true")` evaluate to true?

Comment: yes im sure in both cases, I tested it with System.out. It stores value but cant retrieve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you call getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE) when you save and when you load you call PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

I think it's not same preferences. Use only one of these

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. if you give the parameter like true or false it will Return the value you give.

```
Boolean tmp = null;
tmp = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("key", tmp.getBoolean(""));
```

It gives you the value you get.